# StackNavigator in DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I using React Navigation in my react native app, and I have a simple route, `HomeScreen` and `QScreen` should have a access to drawer, but `SplashScreen` and `LoginScreen` no!

How can I do this?

This code not working and raise an error in read params in `HomeScreen` (that called in `SplashScreen`) :

```
const MainStack = createStackNavigator({
        HomeScreen: { screen: HomePage, navigationOptions: noHeadersNavigationOptions },
        QScreen: { screen: QPage, navigationOptions: noHeadersNavigationOptions },

},  {
        initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
    });

const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator({
        MainStack ,
}, {
        initialRouteName: 'MainStack',
    });

const Router = createStackNavigator({
    SplashScreen: { screen: SplashScreenPage },
    LoginScreen: { screen: LoginPage },
    HomeScreen: DrawerStack,
},  {
        initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen',
    }
);

export default createAppContainer(Router);
```

In `SplashScreenPage` :

```
  const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'HomeScreen', params: params  })],
  });
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved a similar result using this navigation structure :

- MainSwitch

  - LoginPage
  - MainDrawer

    - Page1
    - Page2
    - Page3

This is a working example :

https://snack.expo.io/@sanjar/c28tNT

Comment: You used switchNavigator that no pass params to nested stack!